# react router use params returns empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router-dom

I have a web app which is under development which is just like google drive using firebase. I have this useParams() in Dashboard Screen which is the main page of the App with All the different Folder Routes. So for this screen i have used useParams and now when i console.log(params) it shows an empty object {} and also when i click the button it does not navigate only the URL changes

Github Code :- https://github.com/KUSHAD/RDX-Drive/

In App.js

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './Components/Route/PrivateRoute';
import Dashboard from './Screens/Main/Dashboard';
import ViewProfile from './Screens/Profile/ViewProfile';
import Signup from './Screens/Auth/Signup';
import Login from './Screens/Auth/Login';
import ForgotPassword from './Screens/Auth/ForgotPassword';
function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <div className='App'>
                <div className='main'>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Switch>
                            {/* Drive */}
                            <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
                            <PrivateRoute
                                exact
                                path='/folder/:folderId'
                                component={Dashboard}
                            />

                            {/* Profile */}
                            <PrivateRoute path='/profile' component={ViewProfile} />

                            {/* Auth */}
                            <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />
                            <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                            <Route path='/forgot-password' component={ForgotPassword} />
                        </Switch>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

In Dashboard.js

```js
import NavBar from '../../Components/Shared/NavBar';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import AddFolderButton from '../../Components/Main/AddFolderButton';
import { useDrive } from '../../services/hooks/useDrive';
import Folder from '../../Components/Main/Folder';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
export default function Dashboard() {
    const params = useParams();
    console.log(params);
    const { folder, childFolders } = useDrive();
    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <Container fluid>
                <AddFolderButton currentFolder={folder} />
                {childFolders.length > 0 && (
                    <div className='d-flex flex-wrap'>
                        {childFolders.map(childFolder => (
                            <div
                                key={childFolder.id}
                                className='p-2'
                                style={{ maxWidth: '250px' }}>
                                <Folder folder={childFolder} />
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                )}
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: The dashboard path is "/", there aren't any route match params to list... I'd expect to see an empty object. What buttons are you referring to clicking? There are none in your snippets. Oh, I see, you are trying to also render the `Dashboard` component for other nested routes. Where is the navigation occurring? I assume you have some `Link` components somewhere?

Comment: No the `Link` component is inside the `Folder` component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

After scouring your repo looking for the usual suspect causes for "it does not navigate only the URL changes" I didn't find anything odd like multiple `Router` components, etc. I think the issue is your `PrivateRoute` component isn't passing the props to the `Route` correctly. You're destructuring a prop called `rest` and then spread that into the `Route`, but you don't pass a `rest` prop to the `PrivateRoute`

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, rest }) { // <-- rest prop
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest} // <-- nothing is spread/passed here
      render={props => {
        return currentUser ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to='/login' />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

The routes, these are not passed any prop named `rest`:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
<PrivateRoute
  exact
  path='/folder/:folderId'
  component={Dashboard}
/>
```

What I believe to be occurring here is the `exact` and `path` props aren't passed to the underlying `Route` component and so the first nested component of the `Switch` is matched and rendered, the "/" one that doesn't have any route params.

## Solution

The fix is to spread the rest of the passed props into `rest` instead of destructuring a named `rest` prop.

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        return currentUser ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to='/login' />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

An improvement of your private route may be as follows:

```
export default function PrivateRoute(props) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  return currentUser ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to='/login' />
  );
}
```

This checks your user authentication and renders either a `Route` or `Redirect`. This pattern allows you to use all the regular `Route` props so you aren't locked into using the `render` prop to render the component.